# how to get value from html form to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The value is `null`

html input code and javasript:

```
var tanggal1 =  document.getElementById("tanggal1").value;
var tanggal2 =  document.getElementById("tanggal2").value;
alert(tanggal1);
```

I expected the output `tanggal1 = <input type='date' name='tanggal1' id='tanggal1'/>` value

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Post your `HTML` code, too

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: I am voting to close this as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced without the HTML code. The question does not contain a  [mre].

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="tanggal1" value="value">
    <script>
        function test()
        {
           alert(document.getElementById('tanggal1').value);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLmcO.png)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

`<input type="text" name="name" id="tanggal1" value="value" />`

JS:

`var tanggal1 = document.getElementById("tanggal1").value;`